# It's possible to load an array of tuple from a json file?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, tuples

I need to load an array of tuple from json file. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

my json file is:

> { "broken" : [(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,1)]}

Then I'm using `loadsjsonfrombundle` to load data from JSON as follow:

```
let broken = [(Int, Int)]!

if let dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>.loadsjsonfrombundle(filename) { 

broken = (dictionary["broken"]) as Array

}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: first check your JSON to https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Have a look at json.org. There are no tuples in JSON. You could use 2-element arrays instead.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Thanks I checked it. it seems that json doesn't have tuple type.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. So I will use 2-element arrays.

Comment: Your file is not a JSON file. Any JSON parser will reject it.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes I agree with you. I solved my problem by using 2d-array.

Answer (score 9):

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [
>   (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated
>   by , (comma).
>
> [image]
>
> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

So this is invalid JSON format

```
{ "broken" : [(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,1)]}
```

because `(1,1)` is not *a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
false or null, or an object or an array*

The possible correct format would be

```
{ "broken" : [[1,1], [1,2], [2,2], [3,1]]}
```

in this case you can iterate trough array of arrays and initialize your tuples with array.firstObject and array.lastObject

[About JSON](http://www.json.org/)